# Issues implementing Facebook login with React-native

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to follow the guide here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login
to get facebook login working on my app. I have literally copied and pasted the simple version into a file like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{
  View
} from 'react-native';

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginButton,
} = FBSDK;

var Login = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginButton
          publishPermissions={['publish_actions']}
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                alert('Login failed with error: ' + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert('Login was cancelled');
              } else {
                alert('Login was successful with permissions:'  + result.grantedPermissions)
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert('User logged out')}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
export default class FacebookLogin extends Component {
render(){
  return (
    <Login />
  );
}

}
```

However recieve the following error on the ios simulator:

Unable to resolve module `prop-types` from `{redacted}/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/js/FBLikeView.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
{project}/node_modules

Any ideas on how to proceed?

I tried reinstalling node modules and resetting the cache but I seem blocked.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this by installing prop-types:

$npm install --save prop-types

Comment: Work like a charm! Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

PropTypes is a separate module now, and not included in  react anymore. Here´s the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

More information: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/861